# Call MS Access module function from Python after compiling with py2exe fails

Tags: python, py2exe, ms-access-2003, win32com

I have been running the python code below for approx a year now. But am about to move onto a new job. In order to make things easy for the department I am leaving, I want to compile this code into a .exe file.

I have tried compiling against Python 2.5 and 2.7 with the same results.

But when when running the exe file I get the following error

```
H:\development\DMS_Import_Data\dist>import_data.exe
Run Live or Development Import (L = Live, D = Dev, X = Exit):l
5:3:2012 10:56 Opening Live Database...
5:3:2012 10:56 Assuming Database already open
5:3:2012 10:56 Importing latest DMS Data...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "import_data.py", line 79, in <module>
File "import_data.py", line 46, in run
File "<COMObject Access.Application>", line 2, in run
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, u'You made
an illegal function call.', None, -1, -2146820336), None)
```

Here is the python code. The problem is with the last line in this block datatype = conn.run("import data")

```
import win32com.client
import pythoncom
import time
import datetime
import os
import string
class ProcessDMSData:
    sleepTime = 3600
    ref_date = ''

    def set_ref_date(self,ref_date):

        self.ref_date = ref_date



    def run(self):

        run_type = ""

        while True:
            pythoncom.CoInitialize()
            check_values = ["L", "D", "X"]
            while run_type.upper() not in check_values:           
                run_type = raw_input ("Run Live or Development Import (L = Live, D = Dev, X = Exit):")
            if run_type.upper() == "L":

                update_type = "Live"

                database_path = "G:\\Eurofighter programme Management\\1.PM Reporting\\Production Tracking Database\\booking_planeset_tracker_data.mdb"

            elif run_type.upper() == "D":

                update_type = "Development"

                database_path = "G:\\Eurofighter programme Management\\1.PM Reporting\\Production Tracking Database\\dev_dms_tracker_data.mdb"

            elif run_type.upper() == "X":

                quit()
            print "%s Opening %s Database..." % (self.get_date_time(), update_type)

            conn=win32com.client.Dispatch('Access.Application' )

            try:

                conn.OpenCurrentDatabase(database_path)

            except:

                print "%s Assuming Database already open" % (self.get_date_time())
                pass

            print "%s Importing latest DMS Data..." % (self.get_date_time())

            datatype = conn.run("import_data")
```

Can anyone help with why this works running as a script in python but not when it has been compiled to an exe.

Thanks
Simon

Comment: Have you tried using another exe-packer like pyinstaller?

Comment: Following the advice from Juri Robi, I downloaded Pyinstaller and compiled the exe. This worked just fine with out any ajustments.

I still dont know why py2exe did not work but for me Pyinstaller is a great new tool for me that I will be using again in the future.

Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the advice from Juri Robi, I downloaded Pyinstaller and compiled the exe. This worked just fine with out any ajustments. I still dont know why py2exe did not work but for me Pyinstaller is a great new tool for me that I will be using again in the future.