# pyinstaller and win32com

Tags: python, win32com, pyinstaller

So I'm confused about how to get pyinstaller to build an application that uses win32com. I have a script that runs with no problem from IDLE or command line that interacts with excel via

```
xl = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
```

followed by some other really basic excel calls, then closes. I've seen advice to include "clsctx=pythoncom.CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER" as an argument to Dispatch, but it doesn't change anything. Whenever I build the script, I get an error similar to this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\trunk\iu.py", line 436, in importHook
mod = _self_doimport(nm, ctx, fqname)
File "C:\Python27\trunk\iu.py", line 521, in doimport
exec co in mod.__dict__
File "Myskript\build\pyi.win32\Myskript\outPYZ1.pyz/win32com.client", line 11,
in <module>
File "C:\Python27\trunk\iu.py", line 436, in importHook
mod = _self_doimport(nm, ctx, fqname)
File "C:\Python27\trunk\iu.py", line 521, in doimport
exec co in mod.__dict__
File "Myskript\build\pyi.win32\Myskript\outPYZ1.pyz/win32com.client.gencache",
line 662, in <module>
File "Myskript\build\pyi.win32\Myskript\outPYZ1.pyz/win32com.client.gencache",
line 58, in __init__
File "Myskript\build\pyi.win32\Myskript\outPYZ1.pyz/win32com.client.gencache",
line 649, in Rebuild
File "Myskript\build\pyi.win32\Myskript\outPYZ1.pyz/win32com.client.gencache",
line 65, in _SaveDicts
File "Myskript\build\pyi.win32\Myskript\outPYZ1.pyz/win32com.client.gencache",
line 141, in GetGeneratePath
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename: 'C:\\Python27\\trunk\\Myskri
pt\\dist\\Myskript.exe?844863\\__init__.py'
```

That's copied from this german question http://www.python-forum.de/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=25010 but my error is basically the same. I tried to implement the advice given on that page to no avail either.

I know next to nothing about COM stuff, just hoping to get this little excel app to run.

EDIT: Also tried importing pythoncom and running "CoInitialize()" (based on this guy [Call MS Access module function from Python after compiling with py2exe fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565812/call-ms-access-module-function-from-python-after-compiling-with-py2exe-fails) saying that his script ran fine with pyinstaller) but that didn't change anything either. Really at a loss here and appreciate any advice.

Comment: OK in case anyone needs this I solved it via deleting the 'gens' folder from Python/Lib/site-packages/win32com/ and then prefacing the Dispatch call like so: `win32com.client.gencache.is_readonly=False`
    `win32com.client.gencache.GetGeneratePath()`
    `pythoncom.CoInitialize()`
    `xl = Dispatch('Excel.Application', clsctx = pythoncom.CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are still using py2exe, i was about to try your workaround when i stumbled into this thread: 
[Call MS Access module function from Python after compiling with py2exe fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565812/call-ms-access-module-function-from-python-after-compiling-with-py2exe-fails)

The "solution" was using Pyinstaller that has a bunch of workarounds implemented on by default depending on your script. I tried it with my pywin32 script that uses excel and word com objects and it worked perfectly without any tweaks.